# Executing Twiml After Recording Has Completed

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I started creating a Twilio MVC project yesterday and only have one issue that I need to have resolved.

I am needing to be able to download the recording created by Twilio and process it using Azure Cognitive Services and in the event that the audio does not match, I need to redirect to another action within the MVC project while the call is still active.

Everything works perfectly until the action that handles failed attempts at authentication is called multiple times. I am able to set a breakpoint within the action that performs the verification and once the execution of the code resumes, there are no issues. Obviously, there is a race condition.

Has anyone else successfully implemented something similar?

Is the only option to cause the thread to sleep for a bit? Should I rely upon the callback and re-initiate a phone call in the event that the verification fails?

Comment: It would help to present the problem at a higher level (without going down the path of how you implemented it), as it is difficult to determine what you are trying to address in the question.

Comment: I attempted to articulate what it is I am wanting to accomplish within the second paragraph.